# How can I use a react prop passed to a child using "this.props..." as a mongo collection .findOne() query?

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I have the following code that works fine.  Inside my render methods I can use this.props.ticket._id and get the id of the ticket.  But outside of the render method this.props.ticket._id becomes undefined, so what can I do to pass this prop as a query in my mongo collection at the bottom.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

import { UserReservations } from '../../../imports/collections/userRes';

class PurchaseView extends React.Component {

  renderReservationInfo() {
    console.log(this.props.UserReservation);

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.ticket._id);
    console.log(currentTicketId);
    return(
      <div>
          <div>

            {this.renderReservationInfo()}

          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Okay so down here inside the UserReservations.findOne(ticketId: this.props.ticket._id) ... this.props.ticket._id is not working.  Any suggestions on what I can do to get the prop value in order to use it as a query?

```
export default createContainer(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('userReservations');

  return { UserReservation: UserReservations.findOne({ ticketId: this.props.ticket._id }).fetch() };

    }, PurchaseView);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create container is a wrapper around your component. So you should accept the props in createContainer and then those props are passed down to the component. 
You should also filter data in the publications, otherwise if you do like in your code you will publish all the data to the client.

Something like this should work, but you need to modify your publication in order to accept the ID.

```
export default createContainer(({ ticket }) => {
  Meteor.subscribe('userReservations', ticket._id);

  return { UserReservation: UserReservations.findOne().fetch() };

}, PurchaseView);
```